# React Data Grid Filters Enabled (and open) by default

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

Is there a way to enable filters to be open (displayed) by default within React Data Grid? Preferably one that allows me to avoid passing in the `toolbar={<Toolbar enableFilter />}` prop to `<ReactDataGrid />`

Reading through the [Adazzle component docs](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/documentation.html#/componentsDocs) it doesn't seem that there's an apparent prop to pass in on the main `<ReactDataGrid />` component that displays filters without invoking `onToggleFilter()` via the `<Toolbar />` component.

The final grid component I'm building will render with filter inputs immediately visible and editable by the user, with no need to 'click-to-clear' or otherwise invoke the documented `onClearFilters()` function. This also makes the `<Toolbar />` component (and nested `<Filter Rows />` button unnecessary.

My current component is...

```
<ReactDataGrid
   onGridSort={this.handleGridSort}
   columns={this.state.columns}
   rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
   rowsCount={this.getSize()}
   toolbar={<Toolbar enableFilter />}
   onAddFilter={this.handleFilterChange}
   onClearFilters={this.onClearFilters}
/>
```

*Ideally* the final component would look something like this...

```
<ReactDataGrid
  onGridSort={this.handleGridSort}
  columns={this.state.columns}
  rowGetter={this.rowGetter}
  rowsCount={this.getSize()}}
  onAddFilter={this.handleFilterChange}
  filtersVisible={true}  // Renders with filters visible/active
/>
```

Comment: I've had my own troubles with this component. I went ahead and extended it and wrote my own functionality. Good luck.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, there doesn't seem to be a built in way to have the toolbar & filters automatically open, but a fairly easy workaround is to do

```
 componentDidMount(){
    this.myOpenGrid.onToggleFilter();
  }
```

and then add a ref to your grid so it's filters are toggled open immediately on mount

```
<ReactDataGrid
   ref={(datagrid) => { this.myOpenGrid = datagrid; }}
   // all other set up
/>
```

Comment: And if you want to go one step further and hide the toolbar & button that would allow them to hide the filters you can do something like 
.react-grid-Toolbar{
  display: none;
}

Comment: For some reason, doing this is making the content of all cells in the last column to disappear. They only show up again when I scroll the grid.

Comment: You a genius! So simple solution, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement. I know you stated you don't want to use `<Toolbar />`, but, just for the record, what you can do.

I created my own `<Toolbar />` component. I followed their source code [here](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/blob/master/packages/react-data-grid-addons/src/toolbars/Toolbar.js) and took only what I needed.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
class Toolbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onToggleFilter();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And added that to a `toolbar` prop on ReactDataGrid. The filters are always displayed, no button, no need for hiding anything with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own ReactDataGrid class, and set the state of canFilter=true.

```
import ReactDataGrid from "react-data-grid";

class MyDataGrid extends ReactDataGrid {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state.canFilter=true;
    }
}

export default MyDataGrid;
```

Use MyDataGrid class instead of ReactDataGrid class then.